# How would I compute this integral with a ceiling function?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions, integration-by-parts

It seems simple, but it is not, really. How would I calculate this ($\lceil a \rceil$ denotes  the ceiling function)? 
$$\int{\lceil x+2 \rceil}\ln x\,\,dx$$

First, I noticed that $\lceil x+2 \rceil=\lceil x \rceil + 2$. So I got:
$$\int({\lceil x \rceil}+2)\ln x\,\,dx=\int2\ln x\,\,dx+\int{\lceil x \rceil}\ln x\,\,dx$$
Then I got:
$$\int2\ln x\,\,dx=2\int\ln x\,\,dx=2x\ln x-2x$$
So then:
$$2x\ln x-2x+\int{\lceil x \rceil}\ln x\,\,dx$$
From this point, I tried integrating by parts. So first, I substituted:
$$u=\ln x\qquad dv=\lceil x \rceil$$$$du=\frac1x\qquad v=\int\lceil x \rceil=\,?$$

So I'm left with:
$$2x\ln x-2x+\Bigg(\ln x\int\lceil x\rceil-\int\frac1x\Bigg(\int\lceil x\rceil\Bigg)\Bigg)$$
But now I'm stuck. Am I doing correct so far? **How do I even calculate the integral of $\lceil x\rceil$?**

Comment: When dealing with this kind of functions, integrate separately on each interval where it is constant. And be careful with integration by parts, since your function is not differentiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\int\lceil x+2\rceil\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int\lceil x+2\rceil\,\mathrm{d}(x\log(x)-x)\\
&=\lceil x+2\rceil(x\log(x)-x)-\int(x\log(x)-x)\,\mathrm{d}\lceil x+2\rceil\\
&=\lceil x+2\rceil(x\log(x)-x)-\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil x-1\rceil}(k\log(k)-k)+C
\end{align}
$$

---

$$
\begin{align}
\int\lceil x\rceil\,\mathrm{d}x
&=x\lceil x\rceil-\int x\,\mathrm{d}\lceil x\rceil\\
&=x\lceil x\rceil-\sum_{k=0}^{\lceil x-1\rceil}k+C\\
&=x\lceil x\rceil-\frac{\lceil x\rceil^2-\lceil x\rceil}2+C
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\lceil x\rceil\,dx=x\lceil x\rceil- T_{\lceil x\rceil-1}+C,$$ where $T_n $ is the $n $th triangle number. Between integers the integrand is constant, so we expect the integral to increase linearly. We expect the rate of increase to be equal to the locally constant value of the integrand. We have to subract the triangle numbers so that the integral is continuous.

Comment: Could you show why $\int\lceil x \rceil\,dx=x\lceil x \rceil + C$ ?

Comment: The integral should be continuous, but $x\lceil x\rceil+C$ is not

Comment: @robjohn But I think we can pretend that function is continuous by drawing vertical lines where it is not continuous and saying that derivative of points of discontinuity is infinite.

Comment: @KKZiomek robjohn is right. We what I gave is the form of the integral between each pair of consecutive integers. I'll update in a little while with a more general answer.